# safari url discard '#'

Tags: url, redirect, safari

I hava a issues in the safari 5.1

When i requested the url `http://127.0.0.1/c/horse5#wine`, my mvc applciation will find the static file, then it redirect to `http://127.0.0.1/htmls/venue/4.html`.

My issues is why the safari discard the '#wine'.

In the firefox/chrome/ie9/10, it redirect to `http://127.0.0.1/htmls/venue/4.html#wine`, this is the expected url.

Why safari discard the '#wine', and how to solve this issue?